# Python variables in scapy (sendp)

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to generate arbitrary wireless beacon frames. I'm taking string based SSID values from a file to place into the scapy sendp statement. Now I can put the SSID strings into sendp but I also need to dynamically get the strings length (`len=`) so I can place it into the packet details. The packets are malformed without this length.

This where I get an error "struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer"

Code looks like this:

```
with open ('ssid.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    sendp(RadioTap()/Dot11(addr1="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",addr2=RandMAC(),addr3=RandMAC())/Dot11Beacon(cap="ESS")/Dot11Elt(ID="SSID", len='%d' % len(line.strip()),info='%d' % (line))/Dot11Elt(ID="Rates",info='\x82\x84\x0b\x16')/Dot11Elt(ID="DSset",info="\x03")/Dot11Elt(ID="TIM",info="\x00\x01\x00\x00"),iface="mon0")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your problem is this part:

```
Dot11Elt(ID="SSID", len='%d' % len(line.strip()),info='%d' % (line))
```

If the `len` parameter is supposed to be an integer, that could cause the error that you are seeing, since you are actually passing a string. Try removing the first `'%d' %`, i.e. replace the above with:

```
Dot11Elt(ID="SSID", len=len(line.strip()), info='%d' % line)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. It took me several hours on my own and I couldn't work that out.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! If my answer is correct, please accept it.